# How to add css class by default for all the images

Tags: css, image

Adding css class to all the image elements is a lengthy task and I was wondering if we can add css class to all the images by default. Something like this:

img {class:'hover-share-buttons';}

but the technique doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with this code or am I doing it completely wrong? Normal css is easy to add but can we add an class ?

An answer will be much appreciated. I am trying this on weebly http://geniusknight.weebly.com.
The class attribute comes from an external js file (addthis lab js) and sorry about putting the .img there, it was my bad but still it doesn't work. You see I have no css for that because the class attribute is coming from addthis script.

Comment: Why do you need to apply a default class to every image? And why not in javascript?

Comment: Without dot. Only `img{}`

Comment: Oh yes @FabrizioCalderan I wasn't aware of the fact but Felix and you just made it great for me. Thank you so much and have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use:

```
img {

    // Your styles for all images

}
```

However, if you want to add default class to all images, you need to use javascript:

```
var i, images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].className += " hover-share-buttons";
}
```

or easier if you're able to use jQuery:

```
$("img").addClass("hover-share-buttons");
```

Comment: Oh great I did it. Thanks once again Felix, you are the man! :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to target the img tag alone. At the moment you're treating it like a class by adding a period in front of it.

You should use:

```
img {
   //Your css here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The '.img' selector refers to all elements with a class named 'img', which is not what you need.

You can set css rules directly to element types:

```
img {border:solid 1px #000;}
```

This will define a css property to all image elements.

Hope this helps.